# AWS sendCustomVerificationEmail not sending email

Tags: php, email, amazon-ses

I am trying to send custom verificacion email using PHP and Amazon SDK (sendCustomVerificationEmail)

```
$data = $ses->sendCustomVerificationEmail(['EmailAddress' => $verifyEmail, 'TemplateName' => 'TemplateName']);print_r($data);
```

But user in $verifyEmail never receives verificacion email.

What I got is

```
Aws\Result Object
(
    [data:Aws\Result:private] => Array
        (
            [MessageId] => 0100018bc4d420b2-10b031c0-4256-48ce-b301-0f248ac9b268-000000
            [@metadata] => Array
                (
                    [statusCode] => 200
                    [effectiveUri] => https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
                    [headers] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => Sun, 12 Nov 2023 18:38:38 GMT
                            [content-type] => text/xml
                            [content-length] => 398
                            [connection] => keep-alive
                            [x-amzn-requestid] => 96c83696-4393-4c73-bbab-60596beadf3d
                        )

                    [transferStats] => Array
                        (
                            [http] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [monitoringEvents:Aws\Result:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

status 200 indicates that all is Ok. But user never receives verificacion email. I tried with several addresses - no one is working.

It is strange - everything was working as expected, but around 1 month ago - seems stop to work.

I am using PHP and latest AWS SDK for PHP.

Comment: Hi. I did this - nothind is interesting there. Same Status = 200.

Comment: If you are in the SES sandbox environment, you can only send emails to verified email addresses and domains. Check if your account is still in the sandbox or if it has production access. Ensure you haven’t exceeded your SES sending quotas. These include limits on the number of emails sent per day and the sending rate. In the SES console, check the reputation dashboard to see if there are any issues with your sending reputation that could be affecting email delivery.Ensure that the 'TemplateName' you are using in your sendCustomVerificationEmail request exists in SES and is properly configured.

Comment: All this things a tested. A am in producion mode, template exists. 

Note: I can receive verificacion email using method $ses->verifyEmailIdentity() normally, but I need send $ses->sendCustomVerificationEmail with my custom template

Comment: What do you see in AWS CloudWatch for logs related to SES?

Comment: I don't think I have any alarms/logs configured for SES

Comment: Even in production, the sending email address (in the template) needs to be verified. (FromEmailAddress) Did you change that, or remove the verification status to retest?

Comment: FromEmailAddress is verified for 4 years, didn't changes. I checked in SES console - it's verified

Comment: Check if your version of the AWS SDK for PHP in the latest version. 
Test with different email addresses to see if the issue persists across multiple recipients. 
Also look through the SES logs to see if there are any errors related to the delivery. You can find the logs in the AWS console